# Java Hibernate Annotation @JoinTable Relationships

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join

I've recently started using Hibernate and am trying to get my head around all the annotations and ensure I do things properly. I have two tables 'user' and 'user_friends' that are similar to the below

```
+------+------+-------+
| id   | name | email |
+------+------+-------+
```

and the user friends table

```
+--------+---------+----------+
| userid | buddyid | accepted |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Now in SQL I ran a query that looked similar to

```
SELECT u.id AS id, u.name AS username, u.email AS email FROM user_friends 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = '1' WHERE buddyid = '2' AND ACCEPTED = 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT u.id as id, u.name AS username, u.email AS email FROM user_friends
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = '2' WHERE buddyid = '1' AND ACCEPTED = 1;
```

I've got two classes in Java set-up in a fashion similar to this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private int name;
  private int email;

  @OneToMany(fetch=UserBuddy.class, mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="userid")
  private Set<UserBuddy> _buddies;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_friends")
public class UserBuddy {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id")
   private User friendId;

   private int id;
   private int name;
   private int email;
}
```

I don't know how I would then go about, getting the user_friends name and email from the user table. Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: you don't have name/email in the User class?

Comment: I do yeah, and have updated the example to illustrate that. Would I be able to re-use the User.class? I don't want all the information that is stored in there. The user table does have more information than that, but in this instance I only need the name and email for the user_buddy.

Comment: For instance, the User table also contains information about registration date, and their virtual currency. But I don't need that information for their user_friend so i didn't think to reuse User.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the User object in your UserBuddy, just reference that

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_friends")
public class UserBuddy 
{

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id")
   private User friend; // This is a User not an id

   public String getEmail()
   {
     return friend.getEmail();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, cheers for your answer. The problem that I have with something like this is that User.class contains more information than is needed for user_buddy. User_buddy is only present on a list so requires very little information. User.class actually contains alot more than just an email and name, which'd cause the query to return alot of useless information. Is there any annotations that would allow me to return only select pieces of information for the buddy?

Comment: And how would I ensure that only buddies that are accepted "user_buddies.accepted = 1" are retrieved in the set as shown in the SQL Query? :P

Comment: You could use HQL for the Criteria API to specify that you only want accepted buddies such as "select u from User u fetch join UserBuddy buddy where buddy.accepted = true"